# "The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type."

Tags: c#, wcf, linq

I have a WCF service (services). The services manage the data. But now I have problems by selecting data in a LINQ-query. I get a message **"The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type."**

By debugging the first time I walk through the method you'll finish to the exception-line. When I put back the debugger line (the yellow marked one) onto line "// 08", and then I walk through the method everything goes fine.

```
    private static ResultClass Geselecteerd(int AID_Artiest)  // 01
    { // 02
        ResultClass _Result = new ResultClass(); // 03
        string sMethodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;// 04
        // 05
        try // 06
        { // 07
            var recArtiest = (from artiest in DatabaseControl.GetDatabeheer.DataContext.ARTIESTs  // 08
                           where artiest.ID_ARTIEST == AID_Artiest
                           select artiest).SingleOrDefault();

            if (recArtiest != null)
            {
                ArtiestDataType.ID_Artiest = recArtiest.ID_ARTIEST;
                ArtiestDataType.Artiestnaam = recArtiest.ARTIESTNAAM;
                ArtiestDataType.Voorvoegsel = recArtiest.VOORVOEGSEL;
                ArtiestDataType.Product = recArtiest.PRODUCT;
                ArtiestDataType.ID_Categorie = recArtiest.ID_CATEGORIE;
                ArtiestDataType.ID_Genre = recArtiest.ID_GENRE;
                ArtiestDataType.Is_Band = BasisDataType.GetBoolString(recArtiest.IS_BAND);
                ArtiestDataType.Land = recArtiest.LAND;
                ArtiestDataType.Plaats = recArtiest.PLAATS;
                ArtiestDataType.Website = recArtiest.WEBSITE;
                ArtiestDataType.DatumInvoer = recArtiest.DATUM_INVOER;
                ArtiestDataType.DatumMutatie = recArtiest.DATUM_MUTATIE;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string sFoutmelding = "Kan geen selectie maken.";
            FLogboek.AddFoutmelding(FClassName, sMethodName, sFoutmelding, ex.Message);

            _Result.Code = ResultCode.FATAAL;
            _Result.Melding = sFoutmelding;
        }

        return _Result;
    }
```

**ID_ARTIEST is an integer field and it is a primary key too. The value of the field is required and a NULL-value is not possible.**

**This method has always worked. The problem starts when I add new Service.**

My question is: What do I wrong? Has is to do with the service? **Do I have to delay the process?** 
Can anybody give me some tips? I've 8 service references. If you're missing some essential sources, I can add it.

I have now only a work-around. 
I have added try-catch inside the try-catch area. And then I didn't get any exception. It has to do with the performance. **Do I need an Async-solution?**

Thanks.

Comment: What is the code for the class of the ArtiestDataType object?

Comment: ArtiestDataType is only static class with integers, strings and DateTime. That's not the problem. And Nullable<int. you can't use SingleOrDefault() anymore. It has to be IQueryable object. Is there any object that can delay the process, so the system has the time for reading the LINQ query.

Comment: Off topic, but still important; You should check out [Guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002(v=vs.100).aspx), specifically [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost certainly what is happening is one of the properties of the type `ARTIESTs` in `DatabaseControl.GetDatabeheer.DataContext.ARTIESTs` is of type `int?` (which means nullable integer).

At a guess I would say it's either `ID_CATEGORIE` or `ID_GENRE`.

You will need to modify the equivalent property of your type `ArtiestDataType` to also be of type `int?`.

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: I forgot that I've added an int-field in the table. Everything with an "ID_" in my table is required. I tried all answers.

Comment: Thanks! Pretty new to Entity Framework / MVC 5, and this is the first answer that I've seen for this error that includes the use of '?' for nullable... Exactly what I needed! +1 to you sir!

Answer (score 4):

> What do I wrong?

Except assigning null to a non-nullable element (a struct)?

Your code is meaningless (posting a ton is not as good as actually posting the relevant parts, which you miss).

I could be that the field in the database is nullable and CONTAINS null, but your field is not int? (nullable of int) so it can not assign null there.

I would look in the direction of a database mapped table being wrong. Check fields, check that all nullable columns actually are nullable in the class.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
where artiest.ID_ARTIEST == AID_Artiest
```

to

```
where artiest.ID_ARTIEST.HasValue && artiest.ID_ARTIEST.Value == AID_Artiest
```

One or more of your artists don't have an `ID_ARTIEST` set (which you should fix, it does look like a primary key which should always be present), so when comparing `(int?)null == int` the exception is thrown.

Comment: ID_ARTIEST is the primary key. And the ID is an integer.

Comment: Well there is an `int? some_ID` somewhere, and another `int some_ID` somewhere else. You can't assign the nullable one (`int?`) to the not nullable one (`int`), that's when you get this exception. Hit the breakpoint again and look which ID column is nullable and contains a null value.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, Where i had a ignore duplicate column in the table design.

While inserting on submit, it will return table row after insertion. But here the row is being ignored due to duplicate, It was not returning table row with identity value(which is not nullable).

So the expected value is not present, it will throwed "**Non nullable excecption**".

Before inserting check the row exist based on the ignore duplicate column. It will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable/property as nullable int

```
public int? myInt
```

Answer (score -2):

in my case, the ID was an INT64 and the way to fix it was by using ToString()

```
..... 
group t2 by t1 into gr
select new {t1 = gr.Key, id = gr.First().ID.ToString()}
```