# How to delay a process in a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

How to delay the process in a WCF service?

I have added an extra new service in the WCF application. 
When you call a method in a WCF service, the database are opened and a LINQ query are executed.
But now with the extra service. The LINQ queries didn't work anymore. I've debugged what goes wrong. 
And I saw when I **step back (by debugging)** in the method so I call the LINQ query twice, then the query do right in **the second time**.
There has to be **added a delay** in the process between by opening the database and by executing the query. But how?

Can anybody tell what do I have to do?

Thanks...

In the service:

```
namespace MHcService
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class ArtiestService : IArtiestService
    {
...
        public ArtiestRecord[] GetArtiestlijst(out ResultClass AResult, int AID_Genre, string AFilter)
        {
            Databeheer FDatabeheer = Databeheer.GetInstance();
            return ArtiestlijstToArray(ArtiestDataManager.Artiestlijst(out AResult, AID_Genre, AFilter));
        }

namespace MHcService.Database
{
    public static class DatabaseControl
    {
        private static Databeheer FDatabeheer = Databeheer.GetInstance();
        public static Databeheer GetDatabeheer { get { return FDatabeheer; } }
    }

    public class Databeheer
    {
...
        public DatamodelDataContext DataContext { get { return FDataContext; } }
        private static Databeheer FUniqueInstance;
        private static object FLockObject = new object();
        public static Databeheer GetInstance()
        {
            if (FUniqueInstance == null)
            {
                lock (FLockObject)
                {
                    if (FUniqueInstance == null)
                    {
                        FUniqueInstance = new Databeheer();
                    }
                }
            }

            return FUniqueInstance;
        }

        private Databeheer()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            FApplicatieDefinities = ApplicatieDefinities.GetInstance();
            FApplicatieDefinities.Read();

            FDatabasenaam = FApplicatieDefinities.ParamsApplicatie.Databasenaam;
            FPadnaam = FApplicatieDefinities.ParamsApplicatie.Directories[DirectoryIndex.iDIR_DATABASE];
            FServernaam = FApplicatieDefinities.ParamsApplicatie.Servernaam;
            FDbBestandsnaam = FDatabasenaam + ConstAlgemeen.sEXT_MDF;
            FLogBestandsnaam = FDatabasenaam + "_LOG" + ConstAlgemeen.sEXT_LDF;
            FConnectionToSql = new SqlConnection(SqlServerConnectieString);
            FDataContext = new DatamodelDataContext(GetSqlServerConnectie());
        }
```

[Link of the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952943/the-null-value-cannot-be-assigned-to-a-member-with-type-system-int32-which-is-a) <= This is the source of the method (LINQ query) By this question I didn't get the answers I want to read. So I didn't want to show my source for this question.

Comment: You should look for the cause of your problem, not try to fix the symtoms you see. This is called voodoo programming...

Comment: Yes thank you Peer. Indeed I don't want to fix the symptoms.

Comment: No exception first time, only empty result?

Comment: An empty result. The exception is confusing because it's the exception of the sympton. See link.

Comment: It may be worth showing your LINQ to SQL

Comment: What exactly do you do; what is the program flow that leads to this error? What exception do you get? You say you added one service; what more specific is the difference now to earlier (I can only see code for one service, are there other services?) Are you trying to query for an object that has been created but not yet been saved?

Comment: can you show your ArtiestlijstToArray() code